# How to delete the contents of a blob that are stored in snowflake when the blob is deleted

Tags: python, azure, apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, delete-file

I was building a data pipeline and I used an azure function to be triggered when a blob, which is a json file is uploaded to Azure container which will then produce the data into kafka and the json data will finally be stored in snowflake. Is there any way to get the content of a blob when someone deletes it from the container so that I can also remove the contents of the deleted blob from snowflake? I was thinking of using eventhub but I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted blobs have no effect on the blob trigger. You should take a look at the event grid trigger with blob events.

You can follow this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#microsoftstorageblobdeleted-event) for firing trigger when blob is deleted.

Here is a Sample Event for your Event grid:

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/testcontainer/blobs/file-to-delete.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted",
  "eventTime": "2017-11-07T20:09:22.5674003Z",
  "id": "4c2359fe-001e-00ba-0e04-58586806d298",
  "data": {
    "api": "DeleteBlob",
    "requestId": "4c2359fe-001e-00ba-0e04-585868000000",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/file-to-delete.txt",
    "sequencer": "0000000000000281000000000002F5CA",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

For adding the events directly from portal you can navigate to your storage account -> Events (From left Pane) -> New Event Subscription -> Set the Event and add the End point details in order to pick the events.
[image]

For more information, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-notified-via-azure-event-grid-whenever-azure-blob-is-updated/) to get notified when blob gets deleted.

**REFERENCES:**
[c# - Azure Storage event triggers - capturing a blob being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466994/azure-storage-event-triggers-capturing-a-blob-being-deleted)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to use event grid as a trigger, but I can't get the data to remove it from snowflake as well. Is there any way to get the content of the deleted blob so that I can remove it from snowflake?